# How to resize camera to work with multiple resolutions on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, viewport, fillviewport

I'm working on a fun project on Unity and I want to support all mobile resolutions in landscape mode. I designed everything to work in 1920:1080 resolution.

Everything works in world space, including UI elements.

What's correct way of supporting all resolutions (including weird ones like square 1:1)?

I don't want the scene to be cropped or filled with blue, all I want is my camera's viewport to be scaled to fit the device screen. I don't care if objects in the scene will get thin or fat.

Answer (score 0):

To support different aspect ratios for your `UI Elements`, I recommend making use of the anchors that come with every `RectTransform`. These will ensure that the position of an element is consistent across various aspect ratios. For example, setting the anchor of an element to be left on the x axis will make the origin and pivot on the far left. This means an x position of 10 will position the element 10 units away from the far left of the element's parent. This is made easier with Anchor Presets. Although you can set every value yourself, `Anchor Presets` provide an easier way to anchor your `UI Elements`. Provided you have a `RectTransform` on you `UI Elements`, every element should have the `Anchor Presets` available. No need to change the width and height of your `Canvas`.

Aside from that the `Camera` should automatically resize depending on the resolution of the game view. You can test how your elements' anchoring works with different aspect resolutions by setting your game view's `Aspect` to free aspect, which will change the aspect ratio of the game depending on game view's width and height.

Comment: I don't care about the UI elements. The only thing I want is; in free aspect when I resize I don't want the camera viewport to be cropped or filled, I want to viewport to be scaled to fit the entire screen. let say I make the resolution to 100x1000 I still want to see exactly the same as in 1920:1080 resolution, everything in the scene will look slim and tall tho, I don't care.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what you mean, but I assume you want the aspect ratio to be forced to a specific setting, and have black bars where the window has been cropped. In that case, [this blog post](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html) may be of use to you.